# Usage of ng-click in html-select box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qNFe3Py704BU4aYriiZ9?p=preview) 
if you see that there are four buttons but i want those buttons as options in dropdown..

`<select>
  <option>1</option>
</select>`

but we cannot use `ng-click`,`ng-change` in html-select box.so Is there good way to do that? please edit my plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's almost the same. Here your plnkr updated with option dropdown.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hXtcoKqdRS8AA6r1D1om?p=preview)

```
<select>
      <option ng-click="reverse=false;order('age', false)" value="Age1">Age1</option>
      <option ng-click="reverse=false;order('-age', false)" value="Age2">Age2</option>
      <option ng-click="reverse=!false;order('date', reverse)" value="Date1">Date1</option>
      <option ng-click="reverse=!false;order('-date',reverse)" value="Date2">Date2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: check it once..ng-click will not work in <option> tag